# join two files using linux command

Tags: linux, unix

I have two unix files A and B.

A is like

```
100
101
102
```

B is like

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

How do I have one single consolidated like

```
 100   ABC
 101   DEF
 102   GHI
```

like the first column joined with first column of other file.

Comment: Do columns always have the same length?

Comment: Also try to be more specific than "using linux command". Do you want it achieved with bash, perl, python, java, c? All of these are possible "using linux command", but my guess is that you're more interested in one of the first alternatives.

Comment: Normally you should be using a simple shell script combining `wc`, `head` ..., and not a single command.

Answer (score 2):

You use paste.

```
 NAME
   paste - merge lines of files

SYNOPSIS
   paste [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
   Write  lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.  With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard
   input.
```

The following command should do the trick

```
paste A B
```

Comment: And to use space as delimiter instead of tab, use: paste -d' ' file1 file2 > resultFile

Answer (score 1):

use a scripting language, like python?

```
>>> fina = open("a")
>>> finb = open("b")
>>> for i in fina.readlines():
...     j = finb.readline()
...     print (i.strip() + " " + j.strip())
...
```